# Label can't display when ECharts label's length is too long

Tags: javascript, treemap

I just use the treemap type of EChart to show the data. But I meet a problem. And the label option shows as the following:
    itemStyle:{
    normal:{
    label:{ show :true,
    formtter:"{b}"}

If my data name's length is too long(maybe more than 60 characters), the label doesn't show on the Treemap. The Name will show on the tooltip. Why?
How can I solve this problem? Thanks !

Answer (score 14):

Try to set the grid as below,

```
grid: { containLabel: true },
```

This will adjust your chart label.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `extraCssText` property to set a width and force wrapping. This only works if your `name` has spaces in it.

```
tooltip: { extraCssText: "width:200px; white-space:pre-wrap;" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set desired space in one or both sides of the grid:

```
grid: {left:"450px", right:"200px"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example on the official doc https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-disk

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `\n` within the text labels.

Example:

```
   series : [
    {
        name: 'pie-chart',
        type: 'pie',
        selectedMode: 'single',
        radius: ['50%', '60%'],
        data:[
            {value:5, name:'Institutionelle Investoren\nRest der Welt: 5 %'},
            {value:39, name:'Institutionelle Investoren\nEuropa\n(ohne\nDeutsch-\nland): 39 %'},
            {value:31, name:'Institutionelle\nInvestoren\nUSA: 31 %'},
            {value:17, name:'Institutionelle\nInvestoren\nDeutsch-\nland: 17 %'},
            {value:8, name:'Privatanleger & nicht näher\nbekannte Investoren: 8 %'}             

        ],
...
```

Answer (score -2):

I looked at the official documentation.
It said 'yAxis.nameTextStyle.overflow'.
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.nameTextStyle.overflow

It turned out that the nameTextStyle part had to contain a name such as 'axisLabel'.

```
        tooltip: {
            trigger: "axis",
        },

        yAxis: {
            type: "category",
            inverse: true,

            data: ["very long title very long title very long title very long title very long title very long title", "very long title very long title very long title very long title very long title very long title", "very long title very long title very long title very long title very long title very long title"],

            axisLabel: {
                margin: 20,
                width: "90",
                overflow: "truncate",
            },
        },
```

result:
[image]

Comment: this is not a treemap chart...

Comment: overflow: "truncate" works!